# Using specific data in different grunt tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

So I have two different grunt tasks for my site which is generated by [Assemble](http://assemble.io). Throughout my site, the base URL is specified through {{site.url}}. When I generate the production site, this is equal to pburtchaell.com. When I generate the development (local) site, this is equal to localhost:8000.

Whenever I switch between the two tasks, I have to go change the data file these two values are located in. Sometimes I will forget to do this and upload the files to a staging server only to realize {{site.url}} is localhost:8000.

Is there some way to configure my gruntfile to automatically use pburtchaell.com when I run `grunt build:production` and use localhost:800 when I run `grunt build:development`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your current `build` task look like this, so you can call with `build:production` and `build:development`:

```
grunt.task.registerTask('build', function(env) {
  // Assuming your load early with site:grunt.file.readYAML or site:grunt.file.readJSON
  var site = grunt.config('site'), 
  // Default if env not specified.
  env = env || 'development';
  site.url = (env === 'development') ? 'localhost:800' : 'http://pburtchaell.com';
  // Change with your existing build task
  grunt.task.run('your', 'other', 'task');
});
```